# Reading AVRO file through java and passing as JSON

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, google-cloud-spanner, oracle-golden-gate

Ask is GoldenGate will push(Kafka) AVRO file ,need to read that and convert into JSON form push to google spanner.(New to AVRO ,google spanner) Seeking how to start with that?

Comment: One possible way to use Kafka and Cloud Spanner is to use [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org) to transfer data. Beam has both Kafka and [Cloud Spanner connectors](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/spanner/SpannerIO.java). Streaming support for the Cloud Spanner connector is coming in Beam 2.9.

Answer (score 1):

Typically integration with Kafka and other systems is achieved using Kafka Connect. GoldenGate supports the Kafka Connect handler. I'm not aware of a connector for Google Spanner, so maybe you'd need to [write one](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html). Kafka Connect can convert from source serialisation (e.g. Avro) to target (e.g. JSON), an example of this can be found in the [Kafka Connect S3 connector's `format.class`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/configuration_options.html#connector)

Comment: Thanks @Robin , i will look the above suggestion